# I have a text document, and I want to copy everything in a line after a specific keyword. How would I do this?

Tags: python, json

More specifically, I downloaded all of my messages over google hangouts via [Google Takeout](https://www.google.com/settings/takeout), but a lot of it is data that is useless to me. The only thing I care about is the actual messages, not even the timestamps. Every message in there is a seperate line in the .json file, and looks like

`"text" : "[actual message in here, including the brackets]"`

So how would I extract ever message, and preferably put them all on separate lines in chronological order? (they're all already in order, the top of the .json file is the newest messages, the bottom is the oldest) Maybe someone could download their own Google Takeout file for hangouts to try and do this. Any help would be appreciated. Python would probably be best for this task, but any programming language that gets the job done will be sufficient.

Comment: have you tried actually accessing using the text key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to treat things as just plain text:

```
file = open('filepath', 'r')
for line in file:
    strippedline=line.lstrip().rstrip() #lstrip removes leading white space, rstrip removes trailing '\n' (and other white space)
    if strippedline.startswith('"text" :'):
        message = ':'.join(strippedline.split(':')[1:])
        print message
```

Probably best to just go through the native `json` keyword commands.

here is an input file:

```
"text" : "[actual message in here, including the brackets]"
"text" : "[actual message in here, including the brackets]"
"text" : "[actual message in here, including : the brackets and some ':' ]"
"texat" : "[This isn't a legal message]"
   "text" : "[actual message in here, including the brackets.  Note leading white space ]"
```

and the output:

```
"[actual message in here, including the brackets]"
"[actual message in here, including the brackets]"
"[actual message in here, including : the brackets and some ':' ]"
"[actual message in here, including the brackets.  Note leading white space ]"
```

Comment: will it take into account lines beginning by, say, `(several white spaces) "text" :` ?

Comment: Not as presently done.  But, my understanding was that "every line looks like..." so I didn't worry about that.  Will edit to fix that sortly.  (note I also just edited to handle ':' inside the text)

Comment: @jivan leading whitespace now stripped.

Comment: Thank you very much! However, I really have little to no programming experience, so how would I run this on the file if it was located at, let's say C:\hangouts_data.json?

Comment: See edited version with `open`.  I don't use windows, so I'm not exactly sure, but I'm fairly confident it would just be `file = open(r'C:\hangouts_data.json', 'r')`  The `r` right after `open(` tells python to interpret the string exactly, don't think of the `\\` as anything special.

Comment: how about `import re; p = re.compile(' *"text:" *'); p.sub("",line)`

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the regular expressions commands.  Would this work if `text:` was inside one of the messages?

Comment: Thanks, it looks like it is working beautifully! Now, to figure out how to make a wordcloud out of it.....Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

One way you could accomplish this with python is by loading the json file to a dictionary data structure and then print back the values you want.

You didn't specify the exact structure of the json so if the json is an array composed of objects with 'text' key in them then this would do the job (change this according to json structure):

```
import json

hangout_data = open('hangout_data') #Load the json file into a variable as text.
hangout_dict = json.loads(hangout_data) #Convert the json text to a dictionary.

for key, value in hangout_dict.iteritems(): #Go over the dictionary
    print(value['text'][1:-1]) #print the text property of each object in the array. [1:-1] strips the brackets.
```

Hope this helps. You are more than welcome to post the exact structure and I will provide a more specific answer.